# ImproperlyConfigured: circular import and also urls of project does have patterns in it

Tags: python-3.x

my url of project

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',include('learn.urls')),
]
```

url of my app

```
from django.urls import path
from .import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.home,name='home'),
    path('notes',views.notes,name='notes'),
    path('delete_note/<int:pk>',views.delete_note,name='delete_notes'),
    path('detail/<int:pk>',views.detail.as_view(),name='detail'),
    path('homework',views.work,name='homework'),
    path('delete_hw/<int:pk>',views.delete_hw,name='delete_hw'),
    path('update/<int:pk>',views.update,name='update'),
    path('todo',views.todo,name=todo),
]
```

my views

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from .forms import *
from .models import *
from django.contrib import messages

from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView
def home(request):
    return render(request,'website/home.html')
def notes(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form= notesform(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            notes = Notes(user=request.user,title=request.POST['title'],description=request.POST['description'])
            notes.save()
        messages.success(request,f"Notes of {request.user.username} is added successfully")

    form = notesform()
    notes= Notes.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    context= {'notes':notes,'form':form}
    return render(request,'website/notes.html',context)

def delete_note(request,pk=None):
    Notes.objects.get(id=pk).delete()
    return redirect('notes')


def work(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = homeworkform(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            try:
                finished = request.POST['is_finish']
                if finished == 'on':
                    finished = True
                else:
                    finished = False
            except:
                finished = False
            homeworks= homework(
                user= request.user,
                subject = request.POST['subject'],
                title = request.POST['title'],
                description=request.POST['description'],
                due= request.POST['due'],
                is_finish = finished
            )
            homeworks.save()
    else:
       form = homeworkform()
    Homework= homework.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    context = {'Homework':Homework,'form':form}
    return render(request,'website/hw.html',context)

def delete_hw(request,pk=None):
    homework.objects.get(id=pk).delete()
    return redirect('homework')

def update(request,pk=None):
    Homework = homework.objects.get(id=pk)
    if Homework.is_finish == True:
        Homework.is_finish = False
    else:
        Homework.is_finish = True
    Homework.save()
class detail(DetailView):
    model = Notes
    template_name = 'website/notes_detail'
    redirect('notes')

def todo (request):
    return render(request,'website/todo.html')
```

my models

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your models here.

class Notes(models.Model):
    user= models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description=models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class homework(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    due = models.DateTimeField()
    is_finish = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
class Todo(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    is_finish = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

this is my codes i don't know the where and why this occurs
this is it shows

raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg.format(name=self.urlconf_name)) from e
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf 'studyportal.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns
in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.

Comment: Please include your code in your main post instead of picture. It's easier for us to help you, and it's also better for other people to see your issue, and check if it's the same as us

Comment: sir pls help me in this project . This project is going to help me lot. I HOPE So you understand my worries. I will make what you said.

Comment: I'm completly sorry, I just want to tell you how to improve your question to make it easier to answer. I don't know the required knowledge to help you yet ...

Comment: pls refer to who knows it, pls  help me